# How to do responsive text overflow with css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to do a list like Gmail email's list.
There's a `td` that will get a long text. I want to hide the text that overflows the `td` width.

I'm trying this:

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Cs7/)**

```
<table class="table">
<tr style="width: auto;">
    <td>Solicitante</td>
    <td>Tipo</td>
    <td style="text-overflow: clip; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap;">Este é um resumo bem maior que o de baixo, para ser testado sassasa</td>
    <td>10/12/2014</td>
</tr>
  <tr style="width: auto;">
    <td>Solicitante</td>
    <td>Tipo</td>
    <td style="text-overflow: clip; overflow: hidden;">Este é um resumo bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</td>
    <td>10/12/2014</td>
</tr>
```

With `white-space: nowrap;` the table gets bigger than boxview. If I remove `white-space: nowrap;` that overflow text continues in lines.
How do I hide the overflow text in a responsive table? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `table-layout:fixed;` + `width` in oder to control max-width of `table` or `td`.
 example : table of 500px and your td to overflow at 50%.

```
<table class="table" style="
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:500px;/* any value-unit */
">
    <tr style="">
        <td>Solicitante</td>
        <td>Tipo</td>
        <td style="
                width:50%;/* any value-unit */
                text-overflow: ellipsis; /* draw dots */
                overflow: hidden; 
                white-space: nowrap;
">Este é um resumo bem maior que o de baixo, para ser testado sassasa</td>
        <td>10/12/2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: auto;">
        <td>Solicitante</td>
        <td>Tipo</td>
        <td>Este é um resumo</td>
        <td>10/12/2014</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Cs7/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. But let me do a little correction: intead of `width: 500px` I used `width: 100%` to keep it responsive!! Thanks

Comment: it's all up to you once you understood the purpose of table-layout and its use, do whatever suits your needs :)